# How to store italic text into a variable using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

Am a beginner in VBA. I need to store only italic text from a specific paragraph into a variable. How to do it?

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. Can you please ans with some explanation

Comment: Sorry I misread the question.  Where is the text coming from?

Comment: Then is there no other way to capture only italic text from a document and store it?

Comment: In msword, I have some content with italic text. Just I need to get only that italic text and store it into a variable.

Comment: Record macro when using Word Find feature. Do it with searching for certain style-italic in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following example to look for a  text range with the desired formatting and then process them by storing them in the variable used each time you can append the new text with the previous content of the variable.
Eg:

```
selection_range.Style = _
        ActiveDocument.Styles("Text_Format_To_Search")
```

where 
    `Text_Format_To_Search` will be replaced by the text formatting you need to search.

reference from:- http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_format_code_in_word.html

Comment: How to store italic content in to a variable. I don't want to display it in a document

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to KazJaw. Finally I got the solution and I have pasted below

```
sub test()

ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(2).Range.Select 
Selection.Find.Font.Italic = True

With Selection.Find
    .Text = ""
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute
str_italic = Selection.Range.Text
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you looking to find italicized text and store only the text in a variable, then you can try:

```
Sub findItal()

    Dim italText As String

    'Find italic text
    With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Font.Italic = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Execute

        If .Found = True Then
            italText = Selection.Range.Text
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```